# Spring MVC GET/redirect/POST

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc

Say I have 2 Spring MVC services:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/firstMethod/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String firstMethod(@PathVariable String param) {
    // ...
    // somehow add a POST param
    return "redirect:/secondMethod";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/secondMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String secondMethod(@RequestParam String param) {
    // ...
    return "mypage";
}
```

Could redirect the first method call to second(POST) method?
Using second method as GET or using session is undesirable.

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: do you really need a redirect? why not just calling `this.secondMethod(param)` from `firstMethod`?

Comment: In this example I can. But if `secondMethod` has many different parameters such as `@CookieValue` it would be inconvenient.

Comment: @Yevgeniy The main reason I cannot just call the java method is that I want the user to have `/secondMethod` in the browser address bar.

Comment: then redirect is the way to go... which implies `MethodRequest.GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not redirect a HTTP GET to a HTTP POST. HTTP GET and HTTP POST are two different things. They are expected to behave very differently (GET is safe, idempotent and cacheable. POST is idempotent). For more see for example [HTTP GET and POST semantics and limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966519/http-get-and-post-semantics-and-limitations) or http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp.

What you can do is this: annotate secondMethod also with RequestMethod.GET. Then you should be able to make the desired redirect.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secondMethod", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String secondMethod(@RequestParam String param) {
...
}
```

But be aware that secondMethod can then be called through HTTP GET requests.

Comment: Since calling a POST method n times will result in n number of updates, POST is NOT idempotent.