# Type Get of ajax or Type Post ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Is type: `GET` faster than type: `POST` cause I am curious how both work.

All I know is type: `POST` never touch type: `GET` yet.

What you guys wanna recommend on me whether I use get or post.

Comment: Get is actually in the url bar while post is data sent along with the request I believe. It depends what you are doing really, get is good for stuff like page numbers and post is better for login forms.

Comment: gets are persistent data (can be bookmarked) and posts are hidden. posts are good for file uploads, password/login and gets are good for items using db's for fetching items, etc. Thats just a simplification of gets/posts.

Comment: posting data is recommended

Comment: Please also consider the limitations between two :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966519/http-get-and-post-semantics-and-limitations

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211881/why-get-method-is-faster-than-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that one is faster than the other. but yes there are other differences.

- `GET` sends all data in Query string and it visible to every user on address bar, while it is not true for `POST`
- `GET` has certain data limits and you can't exceed that limit (Dependent on client and server and in some cases proxy server, usually around 8kb) . but for `POST` you can send as many `bytes` as you want.
- If you want to use File upload feature, you will have to use `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Performance GET or POST depends on how it is implemented on server side.

You should more concerned about RESTful convention here.

GET : Retrieve a representation of the entry specified by the url.

POST: Create a new entry.

Look more [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Answer (score 0):

Posting a data is better than an GET data because of some reasons

1. we cont send more data through the url so GET method is limited to some extent
2. we cont send special characters through url like **Emails** but through the post we can send any type of data
3. Post is bit secure than get because through the url you can see which data is going to send to the next page but through post we con't get them **easily** but we can also get them via inpect elemnts in that page
4. File or image uploadings are also done through the post method only but not with GET